# Syntax for row_to_json with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.2

I would like to figure out how to use Postgres' (9.2) row_to_json with SqlAlchemy.  However I haven't been able to come up with any working syntax.

```
details_foo_row_q = select([Foo.*]
    ).where(Foo.bar_id == Bar.id
).alias('details_foo_row_q')

details_foo_q = select([
    func.row_to_json(details_foo_row_q).label('details')
]).where(details_foo_row_q.c.bar_id == Bar.id
).alias('details_foo_q')
```

I would ideally like to not to have to type out each and every field from the table model if possible.

Got the answer from 'mn':

It should be something more like this:

```
details_foo_row_q = select([Foo]).where(Foo.bar_id == Bar.id).alias('details_foo_row_q')

details_foo_q = select([
    func.row_to_json(literal_column(details_foo_row_q.name)).label('details')
]).select_from(details_foo_row_q).where(
    details_foo_row_q.c.bar_id == Bar.id
).alias('details_foo_q')
```

Thank you mn, works great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query generates an incorrect SQL

```
SELECT row_to_json(SELECT ... FROM foo) AS details
FROM (SELECT ... FROM foo) AS details_foo_row_q
```

It should be

```
SELECT row_to_json(details_foo_row_q) AS details
FROM (SELECT ... FROM foo) AS details_foo_row_q
```

You need to use select as [literal_column](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column)

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import literal_column

details_foo_q = select([
    func.row_to_json(literal_column(details_foo_row_q.name)).label('details')
]).select_from(details_foo_row_q).where(
    details_foo_row_q.c.bar_id == Bar.id
).alias('details_foo_q')
```

Comment: it works!  I guess due to the 'name' variable as well as the literal_column

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like maybe there is a solution IFF you are using the latest SQLAlchemy:

```py
# New in version 1.4.0b2.
>>> from sqlalchemy import table, column, func, select
>>> a = table( "a", column("id"), column("x"), column("y"))
>>> stmt = select(func.row_to_json(a.table_valued()))
>>> print(stmt)
SELECT row_to_json(a) AS row_to_json_1
FROM a
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#table-types-passed-to-functions

Answer (score 0):

If other people still struggle with `row_to_json` function, I have good news for you.
Let's imagine we have `User` class with fields `email, id` and we want to receive email and id fields as JSON.
This can be done using json_build_object function:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

session.query(func.json_build_object("email", User.email, "id", User.id))
```