# SQLAlchemy PostgreSQL row_to_json relationship

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy, relationship

I wanted to know if it's possible to wrap the relationship using the server function **jsonb** or **row_to_json** instead of translatting the result in json using python.

When I retrieves the Documentation, I want to have the Image object as a json.

```
class Documentation(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'documentation'
    id = Column(UUID, server_default=text("uuid_generate_v4()"), primary_key=True)
    url =  Column(String, nullable=False)
    description = Column(String)
    name = Column(String)
    image_id = Column(UUID,ForeignKey(Image.id))
    image = relationship(Image,backref="image_data",lazy="subquery")


class Image(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'image'
    id = Column(UUID, server_default=text("uuid_generate_v4()"), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(VARCHAR(128), nullable=False)
    info = Column(JSONB)
    image = Column(BYTEA)
```

Exemple of the sql request that I want to translate using sqlalchemy:

```
select doc.*,
row_to_json(image.*) as image
from documentation doc
left join image on doc.image_id = image.id;
```

SQLAlchemy (current request)

```
q = Session.query(Documentation).all()
```

Is it possible to do it using sqlalchemy serverside (on postgresql) ? (for performance issues)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010083/syntax-for-row-to-json-with-sqlalchemy

Comment: Did not try yet. I will

Answer (score 0):

Right now these are two different tables.  If you wanted to use jsonb instead of just translating into JSON as a property of Documentation, you'd need to move all of the image data into a new column under Documentation using one of the compatible json types.  Since this is a 1:1 relationship, they belong in the same table anyways.